# relation does not exist after upgrading to Django 1.7

Tags: model, django-1.7

I need to upgrade to django 1.7 (then 1.8, etc but I prefer step by step). I'm actually Django 1.6.11.

I had to do some modifications with AppConfig as I have an app called admin with some models inside.

```
# apps/admin/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AdminConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'admin'
    label = "Our Admin"


# project/settings/common.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'admin.apps.AdminConfig',  # our custom admin
    ...

# apps/admin/models.py

class CastingProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    total_casted = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    article_price = models.FloatField(default=0.03)
    ...
```

*Now I have this error when I try to access my custom admin:*

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "Our Admin_castingprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t", "Our Admin_castingprofile"."video_price" FROM "Our Admin...
```

*IPDB:*

```
ipdb> CastingProfile.objects.get(user=user)
*** ProgrammingError: relation "Our Admin_castingprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ...t", "Our Admin_castingprofile"."article_price" FROM "Our Admin...
                                                               ^
```

Do I have to run a migration to update DB or did I miss something ?

**EDIT:**

*I can't use label = "admin" as from Django 1.7 Duplicate label aren't allowed.*

Using db_table = "your_table_name" lead to following error:

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "castingprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."last_count", "castingprofile"."article_price" FROM "castingpr...
```

And here is a model of this app where I made the changes:

```
# apps/admin/models.py

class CastingProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    total_casted = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    article_price = models.FloatField(default=0.03)
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = "castingprofile"
    ...
```

**EDIT:**

Works! 
Great, I just had to add "admin_castingprofile" instead of "castingprofile" in db_table following last advice of e-satis. 
running throught my db gave me the name of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from:

```
label = "Our Admin"
```

This value condition the name of the table. You can see it in your last error line, where the SQL output the JOIN.

Since you probably had a table containing this data before, you should keep the previous name of it. I'm guessing the name here was "admin" so:

```
class AdminConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'admin'  # python path to the app module
    label = 'admin'  # unique name for the app. Used for the table
    verbose_name = 'Our admin'  # name you can read as a human
```

If for some reason you can't use 'admin' as a label, use a label that is a valid Python identifier such as "our_admin" for label. Then for each model of this app, declare an explicit table name:

```
class Stuff(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'name_of_your_table'
```

You should inspect your db to get the proper table name for each model since they are already created. But do so only if the first method didn't work.